# Convenience class for handling Map<K, List<V>>

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, guava

On various projects I worked on, I found a pattern like

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> listMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

public void addValue(Integer key, String value) {
    if (!listMap.containsKey(key)) {
        listMap.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    listMap.get(key).add(value);
}
```

to populate Maps that have `Lists` as values.

As this is such a common pattern I wondered if there isn't some convencience class in the standard libraries or something like guava that manages adding and removing values to that structure.

Comment: Spring has `MultiValueMap`, but there is no standard for that.

Comment: Did you look at the Guava documentation? [`interface Multimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: There's also Apache Commons Collections - [`interface MultiMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html)

Comment: @AndyTurner, `ArrayList::new` is incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: @shmosel cheerfully withdrawn.

Comment: @Kayaman Voting to reopen because this offers a higher quality question and answer (if I may say so) than anything in the other post. Not to mention it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guava offers [`Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap), which is very suited for your purpose:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> listMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

public void addValue(Integer key, String value) {
    listMap.put(key, value);
}

public List<String> getValues(Integer key) {
    return listMap.get(key);
}

public Map<Integer, List<String>> asMap() {
    // See documentation for details
    return Multimaps.asMap(listMap);
}
```

Java 8 also offers a more convenient way of getting and initializing a value in a single statement:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> listMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addValue(Integer key, String value) {
    listMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

On a side note, I would modify your original example a bit to avoid an extra lookup when a matching key is found:

```
public void addValue(Integer key, String value) {
    List<String> values = listMap.get(key);
    if (values == null) {
        listMap.put(key, values = new ArrayList<>());
    }
    values.add(value);
}
```

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that `Map<Integer, List<String>>` is able to store values that `ListMultimap<Integer, String>` can't: the former can have an empty list associated with a key whilst still reporting that key in the `keySet()`; the latter can't. Doesn't seem like it'd affect OP's use case, but it's occasionally an important difference.